# Subscribing/retrieving data from large bigmaps

Tags: smart-contracts

I am new tezos and was wondering if there is an existing stable and maintained tool that allows subscribing to and/or retrieving large amounts of data from smart contract big maps? I just want to create a frontend client that can read bigmaps with over 70,000 keys/values and is constantly growing.

My current naive implementation is to just use an indexer api

```
https://api.tzkt.io/v1/bigmaps/[bigMapId]/keys?select.fields=key,value,lastLevel&limit=10000&offset=[offsetNumber]
```

This won't scale well and I was looking to avoid setting up a full stack solution if another exists already.

Comment: Why do you think that won't scale? Using tzkt api is the best choice in your case.